# get sort direction from jquery bootgrid in C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, sorting

i have setup a jquery bootgrid on a .net mvc web page, it shows me a grid with a few commands,like sorting,search autocomplete,scroll pages. Library is here: http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/documentation

The grid works well, and i decided to send the commands through ajax to a function behind. The library then sends a list of strings to the function, used to handle the grid:

```
current 1
rowCount    10
sort[filename]  asc
```

where filename is one of the columns for which i wanna sort. it could be sort[id], sort[name] or whatever i set my column to be.
the values are pretty clear, the ajax sends to the function the current grid page,the number of rows and the sorting direction.
but when i get in the function i can read only the first 2 values:

```
  public ActionResult AjaxRequestData(string current,string rowCount,string sort)
```

this definition reads the first 2 values from the web page,but cannot read the sort ,because the actual name of the var is sort[filename], it's not an array of strings.if i either declare sort as string or string[],the result is always null.

How should i declare the variables in the action? So far i could read the sort by using formcollection["sort[filename]"],formcollection["sort[id]"] etc but i have a lot of columns and i really dont want to write out a condition for each one of them,is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

**Approch1**. 
consider you have table with columns "col1, col2, col3, ...".
you can use:

```
public ActionResult AjaxRequestData(string current,string rowCount,Sort sort){
    //sort.col1 == 'asc' (consider sorted by col1 in ascending order)
}

public class Sort
{
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
    //... other columns
}
```

**Approach 2.**
You can remove you parameters and parse data manually. (notice i used post here instead of get)

```
[HttpPost]
public object AjaxRequestData(){
    string jsonContent = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Dictionary<string, string> keyvalues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string[] keyvalue_strings = jsonContent.Split('&');
    string sort_column = "";
    string sort_direction = "";
    for (var i = 0; i< keyvalue_strings.Length; i++)
    {
        var a = keyvalue_strings[i].Split('=');
        a[0] = a[0].Replace("%5B", "[").Replace("%5D", "]");
        keyvalues.Add(a[0], (a[1]));
        if (a[0].Contains("sort"))
        {
            sort_column = a[0].Replace("sort[", "").Replace("]", "");
            sort_direction = a[1];
        }
    }
    //now you have keyvalues, sort_column, sort_direction.
    //...
}
```

Comment: The first approach looks cleaner, the second is similar to what i already have,so i will just create a class for sort.thanks a lot!

Comment: @frankiehf your welcome. note that in first approach, class parameters are names of columns, so it's not flexible (you should change it for each table). if you don't need that flexibality (for example you have just 1 or some tables), yes, that is much more cleaner.